# open external url javascript is not remembering the target

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm creating a dialog that contains a button that will open a window and load a website.
Something like:

```
function buttonClickhandler(){
  var url = "https://www.google.com/";
  window.open(url, 'myWindowName');
}
```

I want to give target a name so, in case the button is clicked multiple times and the window is still opened, I'll get the website to open on the same window.
So my problem is that that does not work for me on IE. It only works is my url is from an internal page.
Any suggestion on why this happens or what I could do to fix it?

I also tried doing

```
 var myWindow = null;
 function buttonClickhandler(){
      var url = "https://www.google.com/";
      if(myWindow.closed)
       myWindow = window.open(url, 'myWindowName');
    }
```

But that doenst work either. If I do `console.log(myWindow)`, in chrome it prints DOMException.

Comment: if(!myWindow || (myWindow && myWindow.closed)) might work, but since it is not your domain, I am sure your console will say "Access denied". Last method is to open the url in an iframe in a window from your domain

Comment: my console did not say "Access denied", and I didnt know that window.open was to open the url in an iframe. i believe that if I execute that first fucntion i added in chrome console, it would open google's page. So I don't understand why it wouldnt work for me. Could you give me some more information about it, please?

Comment: Most browsers will not allow the `if (myWindow.closed)` because you have a foreign page in it. If instead you open "mypage.html?url="+encodeURI('http://www.google.com') and have mypage load the passed URL in an iframe, your parent can do what it wants with the window